# Anyone have success configured MySQL linked servers on SQL Server 2017 for Linux?

Tags: linux, sql-server, ms-sql

I am trying to figure out if SQL Server 2017 for Linux supports linked servers for MySQL?  I know its possible on Windows OS if ODBC/OLEDB drivers are configured on the same server as SQL, but wondering if anyone has had experience with this on Linux?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this is an interesting question, and I would like to know about this myself actually...